# Concurrent use of HDMI and VGA monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, vga

Ubuntu 20.04, Acer V5-171, i5, 6GB, 256-SSD

This older laptop has both HDMI and VGA output. We have an Admin TTY1 User `usr-01` to stream video for our Home Theater via the HDMI port.

We currently have a Pi with IoT-wifi and a Browser outputting to an HDMI-VGA converter and VGA monitor. The Pi is proving to be VERY unreliable when it runs for weeks on end. We need to reboot it about every 2-weeks and running sans Keyboard+Mouse, that's a pain.

I am wondering if I can set up a second Standard TTY2 User `usr-02` on the Acer and use that VGA port.

Is there some way we can have both displays (HDMI and VGA) in concurrent use and both driven by the Acer?

Thanks

Comment: Seems there are three questions here... 1. Is the hardware capable of sending output to HDMI and VGA simultaneously?  2. If so, can Ubuntu output to both HDMI and VGA? 3. Can different users control each screen separately?

Comment: Your question is really not specific enough to present a problem that we could work through here.  I suggest that you experiment.  Some laptops with external monitor ports only support the laptop's built in display +1 due to hardware limitations of the iGPU. If you've ever used more than one monitor, you should know you can put different things on each. And you can connect as many mice and keyboards as your USB-bus supports. Please work on this with the hardware you have and if you encounter specific issues, that would be a good time to ask about them.

Comment: @xiota: Q-1: How would I know if the Acer is capable of supporting to both? I have searched the Acer site and User Manual and found nothing to confirm or deny it. Q-2: How can I interrogate Ubuntu to know that? Q-3: Same again as #2.

Comment: @Nmath: I have tried setting up the Acer as I defined but and am asking for a way to make Ubuntu assign the outputs. I am assuming it might be using xrandr somehow, but it is way beyond my current skills to know. **That's why** I am asking here.

Comment: *"How would I know if the Acer is capable of supporting to both"* - one way is to plug in two monitors and see if they work.  Another way is to read the documentation for your hardware.  What CPU do you have?  What GPU do you have?  How many displays do they support, etc?  You haven't done enough to encounter a problem yet.  Displays are usually plug and play.  There's nothing to troubleshoot and no problems to solve until you actually attempt to connect the displays.  Please do this first.  If you actually encounter problems, you will have more details to work with.

Comment: @Nmath: But I just mentioned I had tried the 2-monitor setup but could find no way to instruct Ubuntu where/how to send the data to specific displays. The CPU is in my Original Post! I mentioned I have read **all** the available Acer v5-171-documentation. Not sure if you are reading my comments. _I have tried setting up the Acer as I defined_ that means, plugged in TV and monitor and created the extra TTY2 but Ubuntu sends only to the HDMI. Not sure how I can explain it more clearly than that.

Comment: *"The CPU is in my Original Post"* -- No, it is not.  You only put "i5".  This line of CPUs has been produced for over 11 years.  It tells us practically *nothing* about the capabilitys of your CPU/iGPU.  I mentioned in my first comment that many laptops only support the built-in display +1.  I understand that you're likely frustrated, but insisting that you've provided enough documentation when you haven't is not productive.  I still have no idea what you're talking about "creating a TTY2" for a monitor.  A TTY is just a terminal emulator.  It has nothing to do with displays.

Comment: Consider editing your question to add details about things you've tried and information you've gathered since you first authored the question.

Comment: @user2445336 The hardware question needs to be answered first.  You can ask Acer whether the laptop supports running both HDMI and VGA simultaneously.

Comment: S'OK, I copied and pasted my OP in another forum that **actually answers** questions. I got 3 replies and the second of those replies is making it all work in harmony.